# pthreads processes not showing up in ps output

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm trying to use pthreads to create two new processes which each use a file descriptor to either read or write from a pipe.

I have a main function which forks itself and executes the pthread creator using `execl()`. From there, I run pthreads to create two processes which each get a different end of a pipe. I then wait for the threads to finish, then keep doing other things.

Here's my code:

```
int createThreads(int fds[])
{
    int retcd = OK;  /* return code */
    pthread_t talk1, talk2;
    int ret1, ret2;

    // Create both talk agent processes
    ret1 = pthread_create(&talk1, NULL, talk, &fds[0]); // read
    ret2 = pthread_create(&talk2, NULL, talk, &fds[1]); // write

    // Wait for both processes to finish at the same time
    pthread_join(talk1, NULL);
    pthread_join(talk2, NULL);

    return(retcd);
}
```

The talk function takes the file descriptor and does some stuff with it. The problem is, when I run `ps -f u [username]` I can't seem to see the two pthreads processes spawn. Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: [man ps](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps)

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_create` does not create new processes - it creates new threads in the same process.
If you want to see threads in ps you need to use H option - like `ps H -fu [username]`.